# Laravel 5.3 WhereIn returns unique result

Tags: laravel

I'm having problem with this whereIn. My code looks like this

```
 $arrayKeys = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1];
    $products = \App\Product::whereIn('id', $arrayKeys)
                    ->select(['id', 'name', 'outright_price', 'discount', ])
                    ->with('photo', 'colors')
                    ->get();
```

It only returns the unique id 1, 2, 4, 5. I need to return it 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1. How to do it? I don't have any idea.

Comment: What do you mean by it only returns 1,2,4,5? You mean records 1, 2 ,4 and 5?

Comment: Yes, the records from database.

Comment: I got the records id 1, 2, 4, 5 but I need 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1 . I think it can't be done by whereIn but how can I achieve that records. Thanks.

Comment: You can use a loop to loop over the array or even use a  Like claus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's normal, because there is only one row with `ID = 1`. If for some reason you still want to get a collection with `[1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1]` IDs structure, you need to build it manually by using `collect()` and `merge()`:

```
$arrayKeys = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1];

$products = collect([]);

$productData = \App\Product::whereIn('id', $arrayKeys)
        ->select(['id', 'name', 'outright_price', 'discount'])
        ->with('photo', 'colors')
        ->get();

foreach ($arrayKeys as $key) {
    $products = $products->merge($productData->where('id', $key));
}

dd($products);
```

I've tested it and it works.

Comment: Beat me to it! was just typing virtually the same answer! +1

Comment: Thanks, it's fine to create multiple queries.

Comment: @Rbex, I've found a better way, when it will not create multiple similar queries (well, it will be 3 because of eager loading instead of 18 in the first variant). I've updated my code. In this code, you query only once to get the data and then manually creating new collection from this data.