# Laravel 5.3 whereIn from existing collection - optimise

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table with test dates (Test) and a table with results for each of those test dates (Results).
I first get all the Test records for a particular athlete/customer.
Then I need to get all the results for each of those test records.
I only manage to get it working with a foreach loop. 
1. Is there a more optimal way to structure the query?
2. For blade, is it perhaps more structured to have the array ordered per test_id? In blade I display the test data as headers and the results for each of those underneath.

First option below with sub query doesn't work. Get a db table not found error:

```
$athlete_tests = Test::where('athlete_id', $an_athlete->id)->get();
    if($athlete_tests){
        $results = Result::whereIn('test_id', function($query) use ($an_athlete){
                    $query->select('test_id')
                        ->from('Test')
                        ->where('athlete_id', $an_athlete->id);
                })->get();   
    }
```

This one works - must be optimised:

```
$athlete_tests = Test::where('athlete_id', $an_athlete->id)->get();
    if($athlete_tests){
        $results = collect([]);

        foreach ($athlete_tests as $key => $value) {
            $results = $results->merge(Result::where('test_id', $value->id)->get());
        }                    
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458146/laravel-5-3-wherein-returns-unique-result helped, but I can't get the 2nd collection without the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define relations between your models correctly, you'll be able to get the results in a much simpler and more efficient way.

First, define the relations:

```
class Athlete extends Model {
  public function tests() {
    return $this->hasMany(Test::class);
  }
}

class Test extends Model {
  public function athlete() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Athlete::class);
  }

  public function results() {
    return $this->hasMany(Result::class);
  }
}
```

Now, you'll be able to fetch tests and their results for given **Athlete** model with:

```
$athlete_tests = $an_athlete->tests()->with('results')->get();
```

You can now access results for given test with:

```
foreach ($athlete_tests as $test) {
  $results = $test->results;
}
```

Comment: My models are setup as above. This works beautifully and is so easy and efficient. 80% of my controller function code now replaced with `$athlete_tests = $an_athlete->tests()->with('results')->get();` Blade part also improved now. Thanks